# Добавление списка в словарь

Tags: python

Не понимаю почему код:

```js
l = []
p = {'id': '3', 'name': 'Иван', 'old': '13', 'salary': '1200'}
print(l.append(p))
```

Выдает:

```js
None
```

Comment: Егор, смотрите всегда документацию на метод в таких случаях. Ответ дан уже ниже.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что метод `append()` добавляет элемент в список и ничего не возращает.

```
l = []
p = {'id': '3', 'name': 'Иван', 'old': '13', 'salary': '1200'}
l.append(p)
print(l)
```